# Flask parameter converters 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask

I'm having issues using the flask parameter converter in even a simple app.  No matter what I do I keep getting `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<int:number>')
def number(number):
    return number

app.run()
```

If I remove the `int` part of the parameter, it works fine.  But I need it as an integer for later use.

Comment: When do you get this error? When running the app? When actually calling the resource from browser/curl/httpie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't return a number from a Flask view.

`return str(number)`

Python will not automatically cast the int to a string.